# Unterschied zwischen "gierig" und "begierig"

Tags: difference

Im Duden steht:

> [**gierig:**](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gierig) *von einem heftigen, maßlosen Verlangen nach etwas erfüllt; voller Gier*
>
> [**begierig:**](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/begierig) *von großem Verlangen nach etwas erfüllt; voll Begierde*

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Adjektiven?

Comment: **Begierig** ist harmloser.

Comment: Es gibt einen qualitativen Unterschied. Gierig ist "heftiger" als begierig.

Comment: Was hast du getan, um den Unterschied selbst zu lernen?

Comment: unterbewußter *Trieb* vs. bewußter *Wunsch*

Comment: Schon wieder so 'ne Frage nach dem Muster: "X heißt dies und Y heißt das, was ist der Unterschied zwischen X und Y?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bei Charakterisierungen verwendet man nur »gierig«.

> Peter C. Müller ist ein <s>begieriger</s> gieriger Mensch.

Merkmal Nr. 1 eines solchen Menschen ist oft das schnelle Essen und Trinken. Von ihm abgestellte Flaschen sind dann normalerweise leer.

Erreicht die Gier ein übertriebenes Ausmaß (alles mir und nichts den andern), lässt sie sich wie folgt kommentieren: Wer zu gierig ist, verdaut die Gabel.

Da »gierig« gemeinhin abwertend gebraucht wird, gehört dieser Begriff zur basalen Ausstattung des Lästerers.

Charakterisierungen mit näherer Qualifizierung sind allerdings auch mit »begierig« möglich.

> Wissbegierig war er schon immer.

Ein als »begierig« Beschriebener wird hierdurch nicht automatisch abgewertet.

> Der Zirkus befriedigt begierige Blicke.

Und wenn, dann eher mild.